# React-Router Redirect only rendering part of the component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to implement a React search page that uses URL params for the search so users can share or save links to search results. I'm doing this by redirecting users who submit searches to the same page but with the search parameters in the URL. My problem is that the parent component isn't rendering the Search component when I redirect to it and I can't figure out why. I am not using Redux.

```
const Main = props => {

    const [page, setPage] = useState(0)

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <HeaderTabs page={page} setPage={setPage} />
            {page === 0 ? <Search ip={props.ip} /> : null}
            {page === 1 ? <Management ip={props.ip} /> : null}
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

```
const Search = props => {

    const [query, setQuery] = useState('')
    const [field, setField] = useState('')
    const [activeSearch, setActiveSearch] = useState(false)

    if (activeSearch) return <Redirect push to={`/main?query=${query}&field=${field}`} />
    else return (
        // forms for inputting query and field, submission changes activeSearch to true
    )
}
```

And to show where the routes are being declared:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.ip = // my domain
        this.cookies = props.cookies
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <HashRouter>
                <Route path='/' exact render={() => (<Splash cookies={this.cookies} ip={this.ip} />)} />
                <Route path='/login' render={() => (<Login cookies={this.cookies} ip={this.ip} />)} />
                <Route path='/signup' render={() => (<Signup ip={this.ip} />)} />
                <Route path='/main' render={() => (<Main cookies={this.cookies} ip={this.ip} />)} />
            </HashRouter>
        )
    }
}
```

The resulting behavior is strange: The params appear in the url as intended, HeaderTabs is rendered properly but nothing else, not Search nor Management. It should render Search since I checked the "page" state and it is 0 as expected. If I use the HeaderTabs interface to switch to Management and then back to Search, it *does* render. I simplified the code for this question a lot and if I left out something relevant please let me know and I will add it.

Why is Main not rendering Search on redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  misunderstood how React-Router works. Search was maintaining its state after the redirect (I thought it would reset to its useState defaults when rerendering), so the activeSearch prop was always true and Search was constantly returning a redirect. I moved activeSearch to Main, passed it down as a prop, and used a setTimeout function in a useEffect hook in Main to change activeSearch back to false one second after it changes (enough time for the redirect to kick in):

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!activeSearch) return
    window.setTimeout(() => setActiveSearch(false), 1000)
}, [activeSearch])
```

There's a one second delay in rendering Search but now it works!

Update: I've abandoned the use of the activeSearch hook and React-Router Redirects in favor of plain HTML links. Adding a useEffect with the dependency of window.location.href to trigger the search is a much better way of doing this whole thing. No more delay, no more occasional failures to render.